# Text overlapping itself in tableview cells -swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have some text which goes into `UIView` I have created inside a `TableViewCell`. When these `TableViewCell` become updated the text overlaps itself, almost like the previous text what was there has not been removed, like so: And here I have two different cells, for a chat screen.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let message = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath) as? Message
    print(message?.userId)
        if message?.userId == myID{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myChatCell", for: indexPath) as! MyChatTableViewCell
                 tableView.rowHeight = cell.setLabel(text: (message?.message)!) + 50.0
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
               tableView.rowHeight = cell.setLabel(text: (message?.message)!) + 50.0               
            return cell
        }
}
```

//Class MychatTableviewcell

```
class MyChatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var chatView: UIView!
var dynamicLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}


func setLabel(text : String) -> CGFloat
{
    let font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 18)
    dynamicLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: chatView.bounds.width-10, height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    dynamicLabel.font = font
    dynamicLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    dynamicLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    dynamicLabel.text = "hai"
    print(text)
    print(dynamicLabel.text)
    dynamicLabel.sizeToFit()

    var detailHeight = dynamicLabel.frame.height
    chatView.addSubview(dynamicLabel)
    return detailHeight
}
```

// Same code for chattableview cell too

Comment: Could you paste your UITableViewDataSource and  UITableViewDelegate methods implementations

Comment: We definitely need to see the `cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath)` method.

Comment: Cells are reused, which I guess you don't manage and do always `addSubView()`. But without code, that's a wild guess. So I'd say, it's because of the line 5 in your AppDelegate file.

Comment: Here I paste my code.Please have a look and help me to solve my problem

Comment: @asa - Nothing wrong in dataSource method, show your code for `MyChatTableViewCell` &  `ChatTableViewCell` classes for more clarification.

Comment: `cell.setLabel(text:)` is called each times. Each times it does `chatView.addSubview(dynamicLabel)`. That's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` (and `UICollectionViewCell`) are reused when you use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`. You could avoid that method and create them, but that's not recommended, not at all.

It means that when they move out of the screen, they are kept in a pool of "Ready to use" cells. This is optimization in order to avoid an init from xib or simple init that is time/resources consuming.
They are left as such in the "pool", with all the settings they had when leaving the screen.

In your case, that meant that they had already a `userImageView`, `chatView` and `dynamicLabel`.

So in `tableView(_ tableView:cellForRowAt:)` since you do `cell.setLabel(text:)` which does `chatView.addSubview(dynamicLabel)`, you are adding the view each time.

Solutions:

Why is `var dynamicLabel: UILabel = UILabel()` not a `IBOutlet`? That could avoid you some trouble. You don't have to do `addSubview()`.

Another possibility is to `addSubView(dynamicLabel)` only once and in `awakeFromNib()`. That's what is usually done when the setting of the cell is done by code and not only with Xibs (well, to be fare, if it's only by code, `awakeFromNib()` wouldn't be called and it should be put in `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`).

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 18)
    dynamicLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: chatView.bounds.width-10, height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    dynamicLabel.font = font
    dynamicLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    dynamicLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    chatView.addSubview(dynamicLabel)
}


func setLabel(text : String) -> CGFloat
{
    dynamicLabel.text = text
    dynamicLabel.sizeToFit()
    var detailHeight = dynamicLabel.frame.height
    return detailHeight
}
```

Other solution, but this one is still creating each time the `dynamicLabel` which is overwork (because you add the subview, then remove it).

```
func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    dynamicLabel.removeFromSuperview();
}
```